# Minitest: Capybara error when calling #assert_current_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I want to compare the expected path and current path to justify whether the test is passed within Minitest.

I found the method Capybara::SessionMatchers#assert_current_path. I guess this method can fulfill my requirement.

But when I wrote:

```
page.assert_current_path()
```

In my test, the error showed: `no #assert_current_path method`

I've seen the `Capybara::Session` has included the `Capybara::SessionMatchers`. I'm confused of why I cannot call the `#assert_current_path` method. 
Does Capybara have the functionality to compare current path and expected path? coz use page content to justify the result is not stable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're running Capybara 2.5+ -  the assert_current_path matcher [wasn't added until 2.5.0](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#version-250)

```
page.assert_current_path('/expected/path')
```

Comment: This is correct! The method can be called after i updated the gem version. Thanks a lot, Tom

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
uri = URI.parse(current_url)
```

if you need check additional params

```
"#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}".should == your_path(:your_params => 'your_value')
```

Comment: This compares immediately which has issues with asynchronous path changes (triggered by JS, etc) -  using assert_current_path/have_current_path takes advantage of Capybaras waiting behavior